# How to check before updating an array element in MongoDB/NodeJS

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

In my sample document, I have a campaign document that contains the _id of the document and an importData array. importData is an array of objects containing a unique date and source value.

My goal is to have an object updated with a unique date/source pair. I would like to have the new object replace any matching object. In the example below, Fred may have originally donated a TV, but I want my application to update the object to reflect he donated both a TV and a radio.

```
// Events (sample document)
{
  "_id" : "Junky Joe's Jubilee",
  "importData" : [
    {
      "date": "2015-05-31",
      "source": "Fred",
      "items": [
        {item: "TV", value: 20.00},
        {item: "radio", value: 5.34}
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "2015-05-31",
      "source": "Mary",
      "items": [
        {item: "Dresser", value: 225.00}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My original thought was to do something like the code below, but not only am I updating importData with Fred's donations, I'm also blowing away anything else in the importData array:

```
var collection = db.collection("events");
collection.update(
  {_id: "Junky Joe's Jubilee",
    importData: {
      date: "2015-05-31",
      source: 'Fred'
    },          
  },  // See if we can find a campaign object with this name
  {
    $set:
      {"importData": 
        {
          date: "2015-05-31",
          source: 'Fred',
          items: [
            {item: "TV", value: 20.00},
            {item: "radio", value: 5.34}
          ]
        }
      }
  },
  {upsert: true});  // Create a document if one does not exist for this campaign
```

When I tried pushing (instead of $set), I was getting multiple entries for the date/source combos (e.g. Fred would appear to have donated two items multiple times on "2015-05-31").

How would I go about doing that with the MongoDB native driver and NodeJS?

Comment: can you please make your question little bit clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var collection = db.collection("events");
collection.update(
  {_id: "Junky Joe's Jubilee",
    importData: {
      date: "2015-05-31",
      source: 'Fred'
    },          
  },  // See if we can find a campaign object with this name
  {
    $set:
      {"importData.$": 
        {
          date: "2015-05-31",
          source: 'Fred',
          items: [
            {item: "TV", value: 20.00},
            {item: "radio", value: 5.34}
          ]
        }
      }
  },
  {upsert: true});  // Create a document if one does not exist for this campaign
```

According to the documentation under [Array update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) this should only modify the first element in the array, which matches the query.